# PHP call class in class returns error:500

Tags: class, include, php

I'm having a hard time new a class in another class.
This is an example of the setup:

index.php

```
<?php
   include("functions/userFunctions.php");

   $user = new UserFunctions ();
   $user->validate();
?>
```

UserFunctions.php

```
<?php
   include("../db/userDB.php");

   class UserFunctions extends UserDB
   {
       public function GetHello(){
          $this->DBHello();
       }
   }
?>
```

UserDB.php

```
<?php
   class UserDB
   {
       public function DBHello(){
          return "Hello"
       }
   }
?>
```

Chrome returns:
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

How can this not work?

Comment: isn't that a .htaccess error?

Comment: a 500 error normally means that there's a problem with the PHP - check the server error logs and see what they say. You might want to check to see if class Admin is defined, for one thing - you're referencing that in `index.php`

Comment: I changed includes the example to be more precise.

Comment: @StaticVariable hi how can we resolve it with .htaccess file do you have any code example, actually i don't know how to write .htaccess file for such situation

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add this to the top of your code

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors","On");
```

The right PHP errors would be displayed or swtich it on in your `PHP.ini settings`

Comment: This helped me allot. I could now see that the second include have to was a bit wrong. Thx

Comment: Except don't do this in production environments!

Comment: Following the @rdlowrey suggestion, you can execute the code above only if $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == <your ip address>