# PHP script works on one server, gives me an Internal Server Error 500 on another

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP call class in class returns error:500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12863897/php-call-class-in-class-returns-error500)

I have code that looks somewhat like this:

```
<?php
include 'payTable.php';
session_start(); 

...

if ($_SESSION['fieldTen'] > 30)
{
    $payTable = 'payTable';
    $payTable::run();
}

?>
```

My permissions are set to 0644, so I don't think that's the issue, but I'm getting strange behavior on the server that I'm not getting in the local directory using XAMP.

Every time I try to load the page with this code on it, I get the "Internal Server Error: 500" error.

Can anyone tell me if there's something obviously wrong here? Something I'm missing.

I tried simply removing the PHP from this file and that causes the HTML part of it to appear without problems.

Comment: @Baba, no, that wasn't me. That's kind of similar though, thanks, I'll look through it.

Comment: @Saladin i think the same solution would solve it  ... see :  http://stackoverflow.com/a/12863917/1226894

Comment: @Saladin, which version of php is your server running on?

Comment: @NullUserException Actually, according to [the manual](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php), that is perfectly possible.  That is, assuming the user is using php 5.3.0 and above.

Comment: @NullUserException .. I did as far as I'm aware; it's in the first example of the manual page I linked you.  And it's `ae`, @Saldin.

Comment: @Daedalus Hmmm... You're right.

Comment: @Daedalus - My mistake, it's 5.2.14 on the actual server, and that's probably why it's failing. How should I rewrite this?

Comment: @Saladin Why not ditch the variable and just do `payTable::run()`? On another note, I can't say I'm a fan of this change (allowing you to  reference the class using a variable)

Comment: @NullUserException, I feel pretty silly now. I think you can tell I'm fairly new to this. Thank, that worked. Can you write it as an answer, so I can upvote and accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not legal syntax on PHP < 5.3.0, so you're getting a syntax error:

```
$payTable = 'payTable';
$payTable::run();
```

PHP (< 5.3.0) thinks `$payTable` is a string, so you can't use `::run()` on it.

The solution would be just to ditch the variable altogether and call it directly:

```
payTable::run();
```

On a related note, turn on your error reporting. This will allow you to spot and fix errors easily rather than being left in the dark with a generic error. You can do this by editing php.ini (preferred), or add this to the top of your scripts:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors","On");
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to call a function of 'payTable', but payTable is not a class with any functions.

Additionally, you could be trying to set the session after some data has been output... possibly from the included file?  this will throw an error, but likely not as severe as a 500.

Comment: I wrote the class in the included php file, and the name is correct in the "include" statement. Also it doesn't do this in XAMP, it outputs perfectly there.

Comment: but even if payTable.php being included allows you to create a class of type payTable... you are setting $payTable equal to a string of 'payTable' by using the single quotes.

Comment: @adam It's a new feature: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php "As of PHP 5.3.0, it's possible to reference the class using a variable."

Answer (score 0):

500 just means the server hit a problem and couldn't continue. You need to check the error log for the web server (presumably apache?) to see what the actual problem was. Looking at the code, off the cuff guess could be the case of the included filename doesn't match the actual filename.