# Go to other process after a copy process condition

Tags: php, mysql

I read database to get `$doc_copy` (contain links). If there's link, so copy process start and then go to `mainProcess.php`, but if not found link, then go to  'summary_index.php';`
here's the code :

```
function copyDoc($link, $savePath){
    @copy($link, $savePath . basename($link));
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)){   
    $doc_copy = $row['doc_url'];
    $copy = copyDoc($doc_copy, $savePath);
     if ($copy=== false){
        include 'summary_index.php';
    }
    else include 'mainProcess.php';
}
```

it's ok if there's no copy process. but when there's no copy process  `summary_index.php` doesn't run. what' wrong? thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Your function does not have a return statement therefore `$copy` would always be `false`

It should be like this

```
function copyDoc($link, $savePath){
    return copy($link, $savePath . basename($link));
}
```

Comment: oh, yes, thank you, i've added it in my code, but still, when there's no copy process `($copy=== false)` it doesn't go to `summary_index.php` but blank result

Comment: when you var_dump `$copy` what do you get ??

Comment: I've added `var_dump($copy);` blank result because if there's no link that copied `$doc_copy` is blank

Comment: It should not be black but return `true` or `false` ...... can you enable error reporting see :  http://stackoverflow.com/a/12863917/1226894