# Parse large text file with Perl crashes when run from PHP

Tags: php, json, perl, parsing

I'm using Perl script to parse and create JSON output for use in PHP.

Basically I'm parsing large text files(5-20MB) using Perl, with data as following:

```
XXXXXXYYYYYYYYYYYYYZZZZZZZZZYYYYYYYYYPPPPPPPPPPP
XXXXXXYYYYYYYYYYYYYZZZZZZZZZYYYYYYYYYPPPPPPPPPPP
XXXXXXYYYYYYYYYYYYYZZZZZZZZZYYYYYYYYYPPPPPPPPPPP
XXXXXXYYYYYYYYYYYYYZZZZZZZZZYYYYYYYYYPPPPPPPPPPP
```

The script prints JSON output of each line of data from file:

```
{ "1" : "XXXXXXYYYYYYYYYYYYYZZZZZZZZZYYYYYYYYYPPPPPPPPPPP", "2": ... }
```

When ran from terminal, it goes over 100,000 lines of such file in 1.5 seconds, successfully creating JSON.

But when I run the script from within PHP using

```
exec("/usr/bin/perl script.pl input_file.txt",$output);
print_r(json_decode($output[0],true);
```

it crashed. Though, if I give it file with 2000-3000 lines, it works well. Not using json_decode and only doing var_dump of $output variable works as well.

I assume it has to do with json_decode.

Is there other way to do this? Suggestions? Solutions?

p.s. I've increased the PHP memory_limit to 128MB.

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

Perl Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = $ARGV[0];
my $id = 0;

open my $info, $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";

print "{";
while( my $line = <$info>)  {

    print "\"$id\" : " . "\"" . trim($line) . "\"";

    print ',' unless eof;

    $id++;
}
print "}";

sub trim {
    (my $s = $_[0]) =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
    return $s;        
}

close $info;
```

Comment: What sort of error in PHP are you getting?

Comment: When I run it from console, doesn't show anything. when I run it from browser and do print_r(json_decode($output[0],true)); - shows "Server Error" HTTP 500.

Comment: What about your error log?

Comment: I totally forgot about log files. This is output of last run: [23-May-2013 14:18:06 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/perl_parser/reader.php on line 10

Comment: Break the feed into parts.  Not much can be said without looking at the script.

Comment: You're still running out of memory. You'll need to split the script into parts or further increase the limit. You did restart apache when you first increased it to 128MB, right?

Comment: @Nathan C, I restarted it. >devnull. I was thinking of such solution, but don't know how since I stared using Perl yesterday.

Comment: Why do you want to parse the `json` in `perl` when you can also do it in `PHP`

Comment: @Baba I know I can do it in PHP, but done in Perl work much much faster in my case.

Comment: PHP might be choking due to the entire JSON being in a single line.  Try replacing `print ',' unless eof;` with `print ",\n" unless eof;`

Comment: @MarkoAleksić i don't agree with you .... faster is dependent on your approach am sure i can come up with a PHP code that is 200% faster than your perl approach for a file as large as 100MB

Comment: I have dropped the idea of parsing into json and then decoding back to array. I just output each trimmed line from perl to $output array in PHP. The error disappeared after fixing the memory_limit. I was changing different php.ini file. (new Mac user that I am).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error does seem to be in your php.ini file. This controls a host of configurable options for your PHP installation. The issue for you is most likely the following:

```
; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
; http://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit = 1M
```

That is just an example. But it seems to be the case that your memory limit is way to small. Try increasing it to something much larger to see if that fixes the problem. Like the following:

```
; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
; http://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit = 56M
```

Also note that anytime you edit your ini file, you'll have to restart your PHP server to have the ini changed be applied. This is an easy step to forget and can lead to serious frustration.

Comment: Note that you will be searching your ini file for the prase `memory_limit = `, but its not a bad idea to read through your whole ini file to see what's in there.

Answer (score 1):

If it's running from console the error lies in your php-config. This could be all sort of configuration error from script-execution-timeout to memory issues or script execution rights. In your case I'd vouch for some timeout occuring or script execution rights, depending on how long it takes to crash. Check your php-error-log for details ...

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be done in pure `PHP` but i would just concentrate on the error you are having

The Reason you got `Server Error" HTTP 500.` is because you did not enable error reporting. trying switching on error reporting you would find out that `$output` returns empty array so `$output[0]` is not valid see [PHP call class in class returns error:500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12863897/php-call-class-in-class-returns-error500/12863917#12863917)

When working with `exec` ensure you use  full path

```
$buid = 'FULL PATH TO /script.pl' ;
$input = 'FULL PATH TO /input_file.txt' ;

exec("$buid $input",$output);
print_r($output);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Ok{"0" : "XXXXXXYYYYYYYYYYYYYZZZZZZZZZYYYYYYYYYPPPPPPPPPPP","1" : "XXXXXXYYYYYYYYYYYYYZZZZZZZZZYYYYYYYYYPPPPPPPPPPP","2" : "XXXXXXYYYYYYYYYYYYYZZZZZZZZZYYYYYYYYYPPPPPPPPPPP","3" : "XXXXXXYYYYYYYYYYYYYZZZZZZZZZYYYYYYYYYPPPPPPPPPPP"}
)
```

You don't need `/usr/bin/perl` in your exec because your script already starts with `#!/usr/bin/perl -w`